# EISDIR issue in Azure hosted Nuxt Vue webiste

Tags: azure, vue.js, nuxt.js, token, devops

I have hosted a Web app in Azure DevOps, the application built with Vue and Nuxt.
`@vue/cli 5.0.1` and `"nuxt": "^2.15.8"`. After hosting the web application works fine, I can login, then it navigates me to the listing page. But from there when I refresh the page it's showing this error. `Sorry, check with the site admin for error: EISDIR ..` in the browser and throwing a 500 Error in the console. In my login response I get only access token, there is no refresh token, could that be an issue? or any other settings in the Azure side? We tried setting this in the azure `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`. Still it's not working. Everything works fine in my dev environment.

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,

  head: {
    title: 'BBG Returns Self Service',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  plugins: ['~/plugins/clearTokens.js'],

  components: true,

  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],

  env: {
    BASE_URL: 'https://my-api-url',
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },

  router: {
    mode: 'history',
  },

  styleResources: {
    // scss: ["~assets/scss/main.scss"],
  },

  modules: ['@nuxtjs/i18n'],

  build: { transpile: [/^@storefront-ui/] },

  server: {
    port: 4200,
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-GB',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en.json',
        icon: 'uk.svg',
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        iso: 'de-DE',
        name: 'Deutsch',
        file: 'de.json',
        icon: 'de.svg',
      },
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'i18n/',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    detectBrowserLanguage: false,
  },
  target: 'static',
}
```

Comment: You're using your Nuxt app as an SPA only? Try to build and run it locally to debug that efficiently.

Comment: @kissu, you mean to rebuild it not as SPA?

Comment: How are you using your Nuxt app? SPA, SSG or SSR?

Comment: @kissu I don't think it's SPA, in the nuxt.config.js i can see `ssr: false,`

Comment: Do you have a `target` key in your `nuxt.config.js` too? And since you do have `ssr: false`, you are using SPA indeed. Hence your issue.

Comment: @kissu, no there is no target set. I will add my nuxt.config.js in the question

Comment: It is by default to `target: 'server'`. So, set it to `target: 'static'`, then run `yarn generate && yarn start` to see if the website build for production is running well locally.

Comment: Thanks @kissu, I added target as static and run the commands locally and all works fine, still getting the same error when I deployed in server.

Comment: Which commands do you run on your production environment?

Comment: `"build": "nuxt generate",`, npm run build, which generates the dist folder and works, but issue happens only when we refresh from inner pages.

Comment: This issue doesn't happen locally tho?

Comment: no, not at all. All works fine in my local even with `generate && yarn start`

Comment: For testing purposes, try to generate your project and drag and drop your project here: https://netlify.com/drop If it is working on Netlify, it is probably an Azure issue indeed. I mean, having a 500 is clearly a server issue (so Azure). Also, did you followed this guide: https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/azure-static-web-apps ?

Comment: I shared the same document to the DevOps and asked to modify it. Today I tried deploying a test app with the same settings and configuration to netlify, it was working fine there too. I am waiting for DevOps to check that.

Comment: We created a new Resource in Azure and deployed again. It's working fine now. 
Thanks @kissu for your inputs.

Comment: Glad it helped, I posted my answer!

Answer (score 1):

If deploying an SPA app, you need to have both:

- `target: 'static'` (the [default being `'server'`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-target#the-target-property))
- `ssr: false`

This removes quite some benefits regarding SEO + performance but at least, you still get all the benefits of the Nuxt DX and ecosystem.

---

To host it on Azure, you have several approaches, if you're using:

- a static app, you can follow this official documentation for Azure Static Web Apps: https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/azure-static-web-apps/
- a SSR app, you can follow this one about Azure Portal: https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was the Azure configuration. The resource should be created as Static website, then it will work fine.

Please follow this official documentation to understand How to Deploy in Azure.
https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/azure-static-web-apps/